# Want to run a python script from Windows Task scheduler in interval of every 10 seconds everyday

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I am using Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a Python script to run every day with a 10-second interval. I have created a ".bat" file where I provided the path to the Python script.

In the Python script, the task it performs is extracting tabular data in the "Hebrew" language and creating an Excel file to store all the tabular data.

The Excel file is generated successfully when I execute the script from Google Colab. However, when it is generated after executing the ".bat" file, it throws an error called "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Please verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the file format."

When I execute the Python script in Google Colab, it works fine. However, when I run the ".bat" file where I invoked the Python script, it does not read the Hebrew language properly

Comment: Try to compare valid and corrupted file with a hex viewer or editor. Depending on the exact format, the files may be compressed (ZIP). If necessary, ask here for help (showing the beginning of the files as hex dump).